# Что означает этот синтаксис js?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я пишу код и наткнулся на вот такую функцию, которая просто возвращает объект

```
export const setCompetitons = (data: Array<object>) => {
    return {
        type: "SET_COMPETITIONS",
        payload: data
    }
}
```

Почему эту функцию можно переписать так? потомучто читая о js я ни разу не натыкался на объяснение такого синтаксиса, что здесь происходит))??

```
export const setCompetitons = (data: Array<object>) => ({
    type: "SET_COMPETITIONS",
    payload: data
})
```

Comment: Имеется в виду про стрелочную функцию непонятно? про `=>` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почему мы можем писать не так => { return obj }, а так => ({ obj })

Comment: Да, я прочитал коммент под ответом Sergey Glazirin - написал  ответ почему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
export const setCompetitons = (data: Array<object>) => ({
    type: "SET_COMPETITIONS",
    payload: data
})
```

Как известно в стрелочной функции можно сразу вернуть значение без ключевого слова `return`

```js
const foo = () => 'return this string';
```

js, условно, превратит это в

```
function foo() { return 'return this string' };
```

Но что делать, если нужно вернуть объект?

```js
const foo = () => { a: 1 };
```

иииии тут ошибка получается, так как js превращает это, условно, в такое

```
function foo() { a: 1 }; // тут синтаксическая ошибка
```

Обычные скобки как раз предназначены для того, что бы сказать js, что фигурные скобки принадлежат объекту, а не телу функции

```
const foo = () => ({ a: 1 });
```

На выходе получаем

```
function foo() { return { a : 1 } };
```

Comment: эх, я на чуть-чуть не успел))

Answer (score 2):

У стрелочных функций синтаксис примерно такой

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
```

где statements - это набор инструкций, а expression - какое-то выражение, в результате которого может быть возвращено значение, обязательно!

В первом случае возвращаемого значения может не быть, однако если оно есть, нужно писать обязательно ключевое слово `return`.

Что же происходит, если нам надо вернуть объект? Сам объект имеет такой синтаксис, что он обрамляется фигурными скобками и парсер не может корректно распарсить данные у стрелочной функции, то есть для него конструкция вида:

```
(data: Array<object>) => {
    type: "SET_COMPETITIONS",
    payload: data
}
```

будет означать, что

```
type: "SET_COMPETITIONS",
payload: data
```

Это какие-то наборы инструкций (судя по первому синтаксису) и этот набор инструкций явно некорректный.

Поэтому чтобы вернуть сам объект без применения ключевого слова `return` - сам объект просто заключают в круглые скобки. которые ни на что не влияют, а просто помогают сократить вариант написания стрелочной функции с фигурными скобками и словом `return` в вариант `() => expression`